# font not 'activating' unless there's more than 1 character in html with xmlns

Tags: html, css, fonts

i was working on some html. i wanted to change the font of some mathematical functions to look more handwritten using a local font. here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sample Html Screening Task 2</title>
  <style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Pecita"; 
        src: url("C:/Users/scxrp/Downloads/projects/Pecita.otf");
    }
    .handwritten{
        font-family: "Pecita";
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
        <math class="handwritten" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
        <mi> x</mi>
        <mo>=</mo>
        <mstyle mathvariant="normal">
            <mfrac>
            <mrow>
                <mrow>
                <mo>-</mo>
                <mi> b</mi>
                </mrow>
                <mo>&#177;</mo>
                <msqrt>
                <msup>
                    <mi> b</mi>
                    <mn>2</mn>
                </msup>
                <mo>&#8722;</mo>
                <mrow>
                    <mn>4</mn>
                    <mo>&#8290;</mo>
                    <mi> a</mi>
                    <mo>&#8290;</mo>
                    <mi> c</mi>
                </mrow>
                </msqrt>
            </mrow>
            <mrow>
                <mn>2</mn>
                <mo>&#8290;</mo>
                <mi> a</mi>
            </mrow>
            </mfrac>
        </mstyle>
        </math>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <math class="handwritten" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mfrac><mrow><msqrt><mn>5</mn></msqrt><msub><mi mathvariant="normal">μ</mi><mn>0</mn></msub><mi mathvariant="normal">I</mi></mrow><mrow><mn>2</mn><mi mathvariant="normal">R</mi></mrow></mfrac></math>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <math class="handwritten" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
            <mstyle mathsize="20">
                <mo>&#8747;</mo>
                <mrow>
                <mi> f</mi>
                <mo> (</mo>
                <mi> x</mi>
                <mo> )</mo>
                </mrow>
                <mo>&#x2061;</mo>
                <mi> d</mi>
                <mi> x</mi>
            </mstyle>
        </math>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the code works perfectly fine. notice the space or blank character between the tag and the letters in the code. eg. `<mi> x</mi>` instead of `<mi>x</mi>`

this was necessary as before i put the space there, the font was not being changed even though that is the objective of this code.

my question is **why** do i need a space there? why does the font change only when there is more than 1 character?

Comment: Does this happen with any other custom fonts as well, or only for this particular one?

Comment: @CBroe in this particular example, any font with mathematical symbol support encounters this problem. still not sure why